# Python парсинг wildberries

Tags: python, парсер, bs4

Учусь собирать данные с сайтов. Решил с wildberries. Никак не могу взять с сайта старую и новую цену, в файле просто None или []. Скорее всего дело в том, что я беру не те классы, но я просто не могу понять какие брать. Брал все классы где есть price. Вот ссылка на товар https://www.wildberries.ru/catalog/37115463/detail.aspx?targetUrl=GP.

```
import os
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

try:
    os.mkdir(r'') # тут путь к диску
except FileExistsError:
    print('Файл уже существует') # создание папки

def infotovar(url):
    file = open("info.txt", 'w+')  # создание файла в котором будет все информация о товаре(1 фото, старая и новая цена, цвет, бренд и тип)
    pathtofile = os.path.abspath('info.txt')  # путь к файлу
    api = requests.get(url)
    result = api.content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(result, 'html.parser')
    price = soup.find('span', class_='price-block__price-wrap').get_text(strip=True)
    print(price)
    file.close()
    os.replace(pathtofile, 'C:\') # перемещение файла в папку

def main():
    infotovar('https://www.wildberries.ru/catalog/37115463/detail.aspx?targetUrl=GP')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Просмотрите Ajax запросы, там подтягивается весь объект товара в JSON. Все параметры в нём есть.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wildberries использует клиент сайт рендеринг, то есть он не прогружает сразу всю страницу. Чтобы парсить данные сайты можно использовать такую библиотеку, как `selenium`.

[Подробнее](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2uL_pBQj_sY&t=3s) про клиент и сервер сайт рендеринг

[Подробнее](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Myl8Br5aRf4&list=PLqGS6O1-DZLp1kgiQNpueIMCHRNzgHa1r) про парсинг с помощью `selenium`