# Ошибка при парсинге вайлдбериса через python: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: this._getHistory is not a function Обычный парсинг карточек с сайта

Tags: python, веб-программирование, парсер, запрос, beautiful-soup

В парсинге новичок, практикуюсь на вайлдбериз, при запуске через консоль, статус кода выдает значение 200, т.е по идее ошибок нету, но сами данные с сайта при том не возвращаются[image: введите сюда описание изображения] в коде вроде всё ок, зашел в консоль разработчика и вылезла вот такая ошибка, как я понял связанная с js

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мой код, реализующий парсинг

```
import logging
import time
import bs4
import requests
logging.basicConfig(level = logging.DEBUG)
logger = logging.getLogger('wb')
class Client:
    def __init__(self):
        self.session = requests.Session()
        self.session.headers = {'User-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) 
AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.5112.124 YaBrowser/22.9.4.863 Yowser/2.5 
Safari/537.36'}
    def load_page(self):
        url = 'https://www.wildberries.ru/catalog/muzhchinam/odezhda/kostyumy'
        res = self.session.get(url)
        res.raise_for_status()
        return res.text
    def parse_page(self, text):
        soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(text, 'lxml')
        container = soup.select('div.product-card.j-card-item.j-good-for-listing-event')
        for block in container:
            self.parse_block(block)
    def parse_block(self, block):
        logger.info(block)
        logger.info('=' * 100)
    def run(self):
        text = self.load_page()
        self.parse_page(text)
```

Comment: Ошибка в консоле разработчика не как не связана с вашим кодом.  https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1414662/470333

Answer (score 1):

*Данные может не выдавать по причине того, что на сайт они подгружаются с помощью javascript и обычный модуль requests тут уже не поможет. Попробуйте спарсить данные через selenuim (уже была такая же проблема)*